# How to check number of inserted rows by oracleBulkCopy (ODP.NET)

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I upload a `DataTable` to Oracle database with bulk copy. I would like to know how many rows were inserted into db. Recently I was doing the same thing for SQL Server and what I found was:

```
FieldInfo rowsCopiedField = typeof(SqlBulkCopy).GetField("_rowsCopied", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);

return (int)rowsCopiedField.GetValue(bulkCopy);
```

And it worked (returned me correct number of rows).
Unfortunately this doesn't work for OracleBulkCopy. How to get number of rows?

EDIT: Using OracleRowsCopied event is pointless, because it triggers event after `NotifyAfter` number of rows, which are processed, not added to db. (According to Oracle Documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

With Oracle, you can get the number of rows affected by the previous statement using the %ROWCOUNT Attribute.

Reference: [Managing Cursors in PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#i45288) Please look for "%ROWCOUNT Attribute: How Many Rows Affected So Far?"